# Launch Chrome with default home page (not about:blank)

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile-chrome

All examples i can find are intented to open a specific internet adress, but not just the Chrome browser with a new tab. Se below screenshots for the difference between opening a "about:blank" page, and a new tab:

***about:blank***:

[image]

***New tab***:

[image]

So this is my Activity Class right now:

```
public void openChrome(View view) {
        String url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

How do i ONLY launch the chrome app (so i return to the previous session), OR open it with a blank "new tab" page? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried with using an empty string for the url ?

Comment: Hi! An empty string causes the app to crash. Also if i just pass "about:blank" i get a blank (white) page, not the "new tab" page.

Comment: How is "new tab" different from "blank page"? Does "new tab" contain something other than just blank page? Could you attach screenshots of what "new tab" is?

Comment: @EduardSukharev Yes, the "new tab" page contains a personalized Google Discover News Feed, which is what i need. I've edited my initial post and added screenshots, so you can see what the difference is.

Comment: I've also tried "chrome://newtab" which chrashes my application as well.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**: Since what you're aiming at is not a plain "about:blank" page, what might've worked for you is either `chrome://newtab` or `chrome://new-tab-page` (as can be seen in chrome://about). If both crash the app, then I'd consider it a bug.

For plain blank tab use special `about:blank` as url.

Comment: Hi! Please see my reply under dennis_ler's comment.